facing error while creating spark session using apache livy ERROR RestSubmissionClient: Exception from the cluster
ERROR RestSubmissionClient: Exception from the cluster: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: spark-internal
Facing issue while creating spark session using Apache Livy.
Below are versions using.

apache-livy-0.8.0-incubating_2.12-bin
spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3
hadoop-3.3.6
jdk1.8.0_391

spark is running as cluster mode.
when we create spark session using apache livy with below request
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"kind":"spark"}' -i http://livy-server-ip-port/sessions
It gives below error:
Livy Log :
Creates a dead session
State of driver driver-20240403114538-0006 is now ERROR.
ERROR RestSubmissionClient: Exception from the cluster:
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: spark-internal
Spark Logs:
org.apache.livy.rsc.driver.RSCDriverBootstrapper
org.apache.livy.rsc.driver.RSCDriverBootstrapper   ERROR
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: spark-internal
When i change the deploy mode of spark to standalone then livy is able to create the spark session.
But when we change spark deploy mode to cluster then facing some driver related execption and session is in dead state.
I am expecting to work apache livy in spark cluster mode and able to create session and submit jobs for execution.
